# Random variables satisfying a strict inequality

Tags: probability

I am looking for random variables $X, Y \in L^2$ for which the standard deviation behaves like $\sigma (X+Y) < \sigma (X) + \sigma (Y).$ Independently of this, can you provide random variables $X, Y \in L^2$ which satisfy the condition Var$(X+Y) > $Var$(X) + $Var$(Y).$

Thanks.

Comment: This is basically just negative correlation vs positive correlation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In general, $\text{Var}(X+Y)=\text{Var}(X)+\text{Var}(Y)+2\text{Cov}(X,Y),$ so

$$\text{Var}(X+Y)\gtreqqless \text{Var}(X)+\text{Var}(Y)\iff \text{Cov}(X,Y)\gtreqqless 0.$$

So to ensure $\text{Var}(X+Y)> \text{Var}(X)+\text{Var}(Y)$, just choose $X$ and $Y$ positively correlated; $Y=X$ for nondegenerate $X$ is the easiest example that comes to mind.

2. As for standard deviations (where $\sigma(Z)\equiv +\sqrt{\text{Var}(Z)}$), note that
   $$\sigma(X+Y)\gtreqqless\sigma(X)+\sigma(Y)\iff \text{Var}(X+Y)\gtreqqless \text{Var}(X)+\text{Var}(Y)+2\sigma(X)\sigma(Y),$$

so by the above argument, it suffices to choose $Y$ and $X$ negatively correlated to ensure $\sigma(X+Y)<\sigma(X)+\sigma(Y)$; $Y=-X$ for nondegenerate $X$ is the easiest example that comes to mind.

Comment: Thanks. If $X,Y$ are positively correlated, will than not Cov$(X,Y)>0$ ?

Comment: Yes. Correlation is defined as $\text{Corr}(X,Y)\equiv \frac{\text{Cov(X,Y)}}{\sigma(X)\sigma(Y)}$.